# Embedded Linux LED-flashing daemon: does it exist?

Tags: daemon, embedded-linux

I've seen embedded boards before that have an LED that flashes like a heartbeat to show that the board is still executing code. I'd like to do something similar on an embedded Linux board I'm working on. Given that it's a fairly trivial bit of code, it seems likely to me that someone has already written a daemon for Linux that does this, but I haven't been able to find any evidence.

Note that OS X Server's heartbeatd and the High-Availability Linux [heartbeat daemon](http://linux-ha.org/wiki/Heartbeat) are not what I'm looking for-- they both coordinate system availability over IP networks, or something like that.

Assuming what I'm looking for doesn't exist, I'm also interested in advice about how to write a daemon that toggles a pin while minimizing resource usage. At what update rate does cron become a stupid idea?

(I'd also rather not hear gushing about the LED on the sleeping MacBook Pro, if that seems relevant for some reason.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The LED heartbeat is a built-in kernel function. Assuming you have a device driver for your LED, turning on the heartbeat is done thus:

```
$ echo "heartbeat" > /sys/class/leds/MyLed/trigger
```

To see the list of triggers (MMC activity, heartbeat, etc.)

```
$ cat /sys/class/leds/MyLed/trigger
```

See `drivers/leds/ledtrig-heartbeat.c` and http://www.avrfreaks.net/wiki/index.php/Documentation:Linux/LEDs

The interesting thing about the heartbeat is that the pattern is dynamic. The basic pattern is thump-thump-pause, just like a human heartbeat. But the *rate* of the heartbeat is controlled by the load average!  Light loads beat at about 50 beats per minute. Heavier loads cause faster beating until it maxes out at about 180 bpm.

Comment: Thank you, sir! That is *exactly* what I was hoping would exist. Kind of embarrassing that I didn't manage to find it through Google, but those are the breaks.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use the cron. Its just not the right tool. A very simple solution is to just run a
shell script from your inittab.

Example:

```
#!/bin/sh

while [ true ];
do
    logger "blink!" # to be replaced
    sleep 1
done
```

Save this to /bin/blink.sh, add the following line to your inittab and have init reread the tab be running init q.

```
bl:2345:respawn:/bin/blink.sh
```

Of course you have to adjust the blink.sh script to your environment. Its highly depended on the
particular board how an LED can be toggled from user space (device driver file, sysfs entry, ....).

If you need something more efficient you might redo the while thing in C but it might not be worth the effort.

One thing to think about is what you want to signal with a pulsing LED. With the approach outlined above we can only show that the board is still alive (kernel is running, the process executing blink.sh is scheduled and blink.sh is doing what it is supposed to do). For some use cases this might be fine but more often you actually want to signal that the application running on an embedded board is still OK (doesn't hang, hasn't crashed, ...). To implement such functionality you need to integrate the code that toggles the LED into the main loop of your application.